# Readability of long function calls

Tags: c++, readability

I have been writing code that uses function calls that are really long and are often longer than 80 characters. Normally I would split those function calls like this:

```
LongFunctionName(first_argument,
                 another_argument,
                 finally_last_argument);
```

However, it looks weird when I try to put this into an if statement, mainly because it becomes not very clear what value it is comparing to:

```
if(LongFunctionName(first_argument,
                    another_argument,
                    finally_last_argument) != value_compared_to)
{
    // stuff to be called
}
```

How would you format this statement to be more readable and fit into 80 characters?

Comment: Screens have grown much bigger since the "80-character" guideline.

Comment: @StoryTeller: But still we have to work in split-screen mode very often, if not always.

Comment: @StoryTeller I know, but when I try to write code that could be shared between projects I try to keep to 80 characters per line.

Comment: @Haroogan, You both give examples of conforming to the tools you use instead of getting better tools.

Comment: @StoryTeller: What does working in split-screen have to do with tools?

Comment: @Haroogan, If the code is unreadable in your editor while working in split screen, the problem may just be the editor. I had a similar problem with a diff tool once, it couldn't handle long lines. The solution we opted for was to get a better diff tool.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Would you be so kind to explain or post a link on how the code that does not fit width can be readable out of the box? Tools give you 2 options here: scroll it horizontally or soft-wrap it for you automatically. The former is a useless of course, but the latter is no better too since soft-wrapping is not aware of your formatting style, and therefore the soft-wrapped code will still end up to be less readable and ugly.

Comment: @Haroogan, ugliness is subjective. My team and I got a tool that *would* scroll horizontally because that's the way we preferred to work. Our coding style didn't truncate lines at until 120 characters, and still lines fit comfortably within the allotted screen space.

Comment: @Haroogan, as for the actual tool. I don't recall it's name beneath the mountain of aliases. And I can't think of any modern one that doesn't do what you said.

Comment: @StoryTeller: So in the end of the day it turns out that it is you who is dependent on tools now because without them your code is unreadable. And code being properly pre-formatted and hard-wrapped at 80 columns is readable anywhere and does not care about the tools viewing it.

Comment: @Haroogan, yes, and your **** is bigger. Happy now?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Was not the point, but thanks.

Comment: @Haroogan, don't mention it. Not like I meant it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would consider putting the function call on its own line:

```
const auto value = LongFunctionName(first_argument,
                              another_argument,
                              finally_last_argument);
if (value != value_compared_to) {
  // ...
}
```

You can even give the `value` variable a nice descriptive name that helps to understand the code.

Comment: Exactly.   Now when debugging, you can see the result of the function or put a breakpoint on it.   Nesting functions is very bad.

Comment: This looks like the best way to do it. I thought of it, but it seemed like it would just make the function bigger because of another variable that will be allocated. However when I think about debugging as @SteveWellens said, it will probably even come in useful.

Comment: The area still needs to exist in memory, even if it didn't have a name.

Answer (score 3):

Storing the return value in a variable is the best solution imo. But you can do something else :

```
if (value_compared_to != LongFunctionName(first_argument,
                                          another_argument,
                                          finally_last_argument))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1)

Accept that it looks this way

OR

2)

Evaluate the return value of the function-call in a separate Statement (pseudo-code)

```
retval = LongFunctioName(first_argument, second_argument, third_argument);
if(retval != desired_val) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't get us started on that one, I would do

```
if
(       LongFunctionName
        (       first_argument
        ,       another_argument
        ,       finally_last_argument
        ) != value_compared_to
)
{
        // stuff to be called
}
```

Comment: No, no, no. It looks more like some jumping words around punctuation marks, not like a logical code. I would argue that such code is hard to maintain.